# Unable to Open issue with Outlook for iOS Add-in

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook Add-in created with office.js in two different testing environments. In both environments I have different iPhones connected via wifi.

Sometimes when I try open the add-in, the iPhone shows a message that it doesn't have a connection.

[image: Screen Shot]

This problem is occurring randomly. The add-in works fine on Outlook for Web, Windows and Mac.

How should I go about debugging this problem? or the solution?

Comment: The first step in ensuring the device is able to reach the server (i.e. rule out network/wifi issues). When it fails, are you able see the iPhone requesting the add-in's page from web server's side?

Comment: Yes, the device is able to reach the server. I've downloaded the net Analyzer app and while I test the add-in, this app was doing ping to server and all pings response success

Comment: Just to clarify, when you get a failure are you able to see the HTTP request in the server's logs? This is different than simply pinging the server. What we're trying to sort out is did the web server get the HTTP request and did it respond correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Some recommendations on tools for debugging iOS add-ins can be found [here](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac). [Fiddlr](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configureforios) can also be configured to work with iOS.